# "Count characters" program: While loop not terminating on EOF

Tags: c, while-loop, eof

Following "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie, I am trying to enter the program described on page 18 (see below).

The only changes I made were to add "int" before "main" and "return 0;" before closing the brackets.

When I run the program in Terminal (Mac OS 10.15) I am prompted to enter an input. After I enter the input I am prompted to enter an input again - the "printf" line is apparently never reached and so the number of characters is never displayed.

Can anyone help me with the reason why EOF is never reached letting the while loop exit? I read some other answers suggesting CTRL + D or CTRL + Z, but I thought this shouldn't require extra input. (I was able to get the loop to exit with CTRL + D).

I have also pasted my code and the terminal window below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while( getchar() != EOF )
        ++nc;

    printf("%ld\n", nc);

    return 0;
}
```

**From pg. 18 of "The C Programming Language**

[image: Image from pg. 18 of "The C Programming Language"]

**My screenshot**

[image: My Terminal and code screenshot]

Comment: The screen shot shows you stopped the program with `Ctrl-C` not with `Ctrl-D` as stated.

Comment: Sorry bout that - updated pic to include both scenarios. On an unrelated question I was wondering why the letter D is included when the number of characters is fewer than 10 - but if that's another topic then never mind.

Comment: You have nothing in your code to prompt for input. Have you thought about `echo "count these characters" | ./count`? Or `./count < somefile`?

Comment: Haven't even learned how to use those methods yet, I was just following the suggested program in the book for now. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

EOF means end of file; newlines are not ends of files. You need to press CTRL+D to give the terminal an EOF signal, that's why you're never exiting your while loop.

If you were to give a file as input instead of through the command line, then you would not need to press CTRL+D

Comment: when you press enter you're still just incrementing NC because the only way the loop will end is if you press CTRL+D; once that button is pressed then it will return the value of NC. The while loop is updating the value of NC the entire time!

Comment: Thanks but I'm still not clear how this works. When I enter "test" and press enter, command goes back to the loop, correct? Then it will scan all the letters one by one.

When the loop reads all of the characters there are no more characters to be read. At this point is there nothing saying that it has reached the end of the input? I thought that was what EOF is. Is there nothing indicating the end of user input that could be used in this manner?

Comment: The command goes back to the while loop after every single CHARACTER! not just enter. You indicate EOF as a user by pressing CTRL+D. When you press CTRL+D that is you indicating end of file(input)

Answer (score 2):

You already have the correct answer: when entering data at the terminal, Ctrl-D is the proper way to indicate "I'm done" to the terminal driver so that it sends an EOF condition to your program (Ctrl-Z on Windows). Ctrl-C breaks out of your program early.

If you ran this program with a redirect from an actual file, it would properly count the characters in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the two good answers I would stress that `EOF` does not naturally occur in `stdin` like in other files, a signal from the user must be sent, as you already stated in your question.

Think about it for a second, your input is a number of characters and in the end you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so the last character present in `stdin` is a newline character not `EOF`. For it to work `EOF` would have to be inputed, and that is precisely what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for Linux/Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for Windows, do.

As @DavidC.Rankin correctly pointed out `EOF` can also occur on `stdin` through bash piping e.g. `echo "count this" | ./count` or redirecting e.g. `./count < somefile`, where `somefile` would be a text file with the contents you want to pass to `stdin`.

By the way <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> just ends the program, whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> ends the loop and continues the program execution.

For a single line input from the command line you can use something like:

```
int c = 0;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'){
    ++nc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Just got it to work using '\n'. Also updated my question to display the code as text :)

Comment: A short explanation of when `EOF` occurs on `stdin` may be better, e.g. `echo "count this" | ./count` or `./count < somefile` most certainly provide `EOF` on `stdin`, with user input -- the user must manually generate `EOF` as you explain.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yes that is certainly a good adition, well noted.